# Is specializing to a birational morphism a generic property?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:Z\times X\to Y$ be a morphism of irreducible algebraic varieties over a field $K$, where $\dim(X)=\dim(Y)$. Suppose that there is a $z_0$ on $Z$ such that $x\mapsto f(z_0,x)$ is a birational morphism from $X$ to $Y$. Does that mean that $x\mapsto f(z,x)$ is a birational morphism from $X$ to $Y$ for $z$ generic?

More generally: if there is a $z_0$ on $Z$ such that $x\mapsto f(z_0,x)$ is a dominant morphism of degree $d$, does that mean that $x\mapsto f(z,x)$ is
a dominant morphism of degree $d$ for $z$ generic?

Comment: Unfortunately birationality is not a generic property.  Let $d>1$ be an integer.  Let $X$ and $Y$ both be $\mathbb{A}^1$ with coordinate $x$, resp. $y$.  Let $Z$ also be $\mathbb{A}^1$ with coordinate $z$.  Now consider $f(z,x) = zx^d + x$.  For the special point $z_0=0$, this morphism is an isomorphism from $X$ to $Y$.  However, for $z_0\neq 0$, this is a finite $d$-to-$1$ morphism.  On the other hand, being dominant is a generic property (in characteristic $0$ you can deduce this from Sard's theorem).

Comment: Aw shucks. Yes, I knew about genericity.

Comment: I'd imagine the inequality for the degree goes in the other direction, then? That is, if there is a $z_0$ on $Z$ such that $x\mapsto f(z_0,x)$ is a dominant morphism of degree $d$, then $x\mapsto f(z,x)$ is a dominant morphism of degree *at least* $d$ for $z$ generic?